# Error on trying to search and delete Register SubKeyTree

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to remove some keys from register based on an array of paths which I would search for a few keywords and want to delete the "Tree" where the subkey was found.

But after trying to figure it out, the script down below is always returning this error:

```
It's not possible to call a method in an expression witha null value.
At line:17 character:1
+ $SubKeys=$RegisterKey.GetSubKeyNames()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

---

```
Begin
{
     $computername = $env:computername
     "Script Started $(Get-Date)"
     [array]$KeysToRemove="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall","HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Classes\\Installer\\Products","HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\OnlineManagement","HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Installer\\UserData\\S-1-5-18\\Products","HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Installer\\UserData\\S-1-5-18\\Components","HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\Installer\\Products"
}
Process
{
     foreach($keys in $KeysToRemove)
     {
          if($KeysToRemove -eq "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\Installer\\Products")
          {$Register = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('ClassesRoot', $computername)}
          else {$Register = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $computername)}

          $RegisterKey = $Register.OpenSubKey($keys)

          $SubKeys=$RegisterKey.GetSubKeyNames()

          foreach($key in $SubKeys){
               if($key.Contains('Microsoft\.Intune'))
               {
                    "Key found: $key"
                    "Deleting it from register."
                    $Register.DeleteSubKeyTree($key)
               }
               else {"No key was found."}
          }

     }
"Script Ended $(Get-Date)"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to watch out for:

## \\

In PowerShell, the string escape character is a backtick `` ` ``, not a backslash `\`. Don't attempt to escape `\` inside your registry key strings, it's entirely unnecessary.

## HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Since you've already opened the base key (either `HKLM` or `HKCR`), you only need to specify the *relative* path to the key - this is most likely why it fails:

```
$HKLMRegistry = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $computername)
$UninstallKey = $HKLMRegistry.OpenSubkey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall")

# Now you can call GetSubKeyNames()
$SubKeyNames = $UninstallKey.GetSubKeyNames()
```

If you want to iterate over all values on a given key, use the `GetValueNames()` and `GetValue()` methods:

```
$UninstallKey.GetValueNames() |ForEach-Object {
    $Value = $UninstallKey.GetValue($_)
    Write-Host 'Value name: {0} had data: {1}' -f $_,$Value
}
```

Comment: This function returns the SubKeyNames, how can I seearch inside every value of this Subkey?

Comment: $Value = $UninstallKey.GetValue($_)

Every time it runs it asks for some values to be passed as a parameter.
Follow the message down below:

cmdlet ForEach-Object on position 1 of command 1 of pipeline
Provide values for the next parameters:
Process[0]: 

Tried to debug it and none value is being catched on the $Value variable.